# Regex that remove painting logic and just keep the column name

Tags: python, regex, sql-parser

I have below String and I want to remove formatting and keep just column name. Can someone suggest regex for this please?

```
"XYZ_Col,to_timestamp(CREATE_DT,'yyyyMMdd HHmmss')CREATE_DT,ABC_Col,DEF_Col"
```

to

```
"XYZ_Col,CREATE_DT,ABC_Col,DEF_Col"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is *painting logic*?

Comment: i meant im transforming date column here. so I just want to remove this formatting

Comment: An SQL parser might be a better idea than a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
regexp_extract(regexp_replace(column_name, \"\'\", \"\\\\''\") , '[^)]*$',0)
```